# Could not find a part of the path with network path

Tags: c#, directory

I'm basically creating a directory in MyDocuments. I think it's worth mentioning that MyDocuments at my company is a network path.

```
    var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

path = Path.Combine(path, string.Format(@"A\XXX\C\{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}", startTime));

    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }
```

The issue here is quite funny. It was working fine for 2 years and recently I cleaned manually path in subdirectory 'XXX'. Now it doesn't work. If I change 'XXX' to anything else it works. It looks like something is wrong with this particular directory. I can delete that directory manually and recreate it in windows explorer. It happens when running from VS2015 and from exec as well. Any ideas?

Edit:
Just to clarify:
Exception thrown: `"Could not find a part of the path"`
In Line   `Directory.CreateDirectory(path);`

Edit:
The reproduce in windows explorer:

I can create and remove XXX and C this is fine. When I tried to create any subdirectory in C windows explorer hangs. So I removed the entire A directory and now when I try to create it manually I can't recreate A because it says that the folder or a file in it is open in another program. How is it possible if it doesn't exist.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is never a valid description.

Comment: @PeterB "Could not find a part of the path" is not a valid description?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakline in the program and investigating what is in your path variable?

Comment: @T_Bacon yes, path is correct. i.e. \\serverpath\\A\XXX\C\20161010.

Comment: It is possible that the path that you manually deleted is locked up in a stale file handle, that may only be released if the machine is rebooted. Until then the path could still be there "in a state of being deleted".

Comment: @PeterB Yes I thought that windows could've messed up with this path. Rebooting doesn't solve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: If you already managed to create a new "XXX" folder, check if access rights are sufficient to allow write access for your application. For testing you could enable "Full control" to the relevant user, then perhaps reduce to what is needed.

Comment: @PeterB ah sorry it's even more complicated. I can create and remove XXX and C this is fine. When I tried to create any subdirectory in C windows explorer hangs. So I removed the entire A directory and now when I try to create it manually I can't recreate A because it says that the folder or a file in it is open in another program. How is it possible if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Maybe this video can shed some light: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWyUFgdAFPI - also there are various related videos on the same subject, let us know if something helped.

Comment: @PeterB thanks, Ill take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. In your company we use sync center to synchronize data on this shared drive. The root directory wasn't fully synchronized so whenever I tried to create directory it thrown an error. After synchronizing and deleting it from my mirrored version and sync center version I could create it again.